# Unexpected NameError in Python

Tags: python, variables, exception, nameerror, try-except

```
>>> e = 'e'
>>> e
'e'
>>> try: raise Exception
except Exception as e:
    e = 'e'
    a = 'a'

>>> e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#333>", line 1, in <module>
    e
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
>>> a
'a'
```

I have not noticed this behavior before. Why is it that using a variable as a try-except alias makes it lose its previous definition?

Comment: It's a strange side effect.  `try`/`except` (like `if`/`else`) do not create a new namespace, so the `e` there is definitely going to wipe out your global `e`.  The fact that it evaporates after the `except` is only slightly surprising,

Comment: @SuperStormer I think it does